# JavaFX: How to restrict manipulation of TextArea to last row?

Tags: java, javafx, console, textarea, javafx-8

I am trying to simulate a shell using JavaFX. I want to handle both the output and input in the same TextArea, so I want to be able to edit and write to **only** the last row of the TextArea where the prompt is, just like a shell.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I suggest to use a transparently styled textfield for input, with Text or TextFlow for output. Put them into VBox one after another.

Comment: @UlukBiy Scrolling would be pretty weird, though, no?

Comment: @James_D, it can be managed by using other layouts and bindings, but your answer below is more neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `TextArea` and prevent changes to the text if there are newlines after the point at which the edit occurs. According to [Richard Bair's blog post](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/restricting-input-on-a-textfield/), the only methods you need to override are `replaceText()` and `replaceSelection`.

Here is a quick example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConsoleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(new Console()), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Console extends TextArea {
        @Override
        public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
            String current = getText();
            // only insert if no new lines after insert position:
            if (! current.substring(start).contains("\n")) {
                super.replaceText(start, end, text);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void replaceSelection(String text) {
            String current = getText();
            int selectionStart = getSelection().getStart();
            if (! current.substring(selectionStart).contains("\n")) {
                super.replaceSelection(text);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want to display a prompt (which is not editable, of course), then the logic is a little trickier, but should be reasonably straightforward. You may also need some special handling for the case where the `text` parameter passed into those methods contains newlines.